# snowflake-sdk: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'async_hooks' in 'C:\projectname\node_modules\vm2\lib'

Tags: javascript, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, cypress, async-hooks, cypress-task

I am trying to integrate Snowflake in my Cypress tests but it keeps on throwing error while compiling.
Error:

```
Error: Webpack Compilation Error
./node_modules/vm2/lib/resolver-compat.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'async_hooks' in 'C:\snowflake\node_modules\vm2\lib'
resolve 'async_hooks' in 'C:\snowflake\node_modules\vm2\lib'
  Parsed request is a module
  using description file: C:\snowflake\node_modules\vm2\package.json (relative path: ./lib)
    Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
```

Tried the following simple steps:

1. Installed Cypress
2. Installed snowflake-sdk through npm
3. Created a spec file and imported:

```
const snowflake = require("snowflake-sdk");
```

When I run the spec file, I am getting the error as above.

If I trace the error to the file `resolver-compat.js`, I can see the import where it fails.

```
    const {AsyncResource} = require('async_hooks');
```

I have manually done npm install `async_hooks` but no luck there also.

package.json

```
"devDependencies": {
    "cypress": "^11.2.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "async_hooks": "^1.0.0",
    "snowflake-sdk": "^1.6.16"
  }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The snowflake-sdk is a NodeJs package, so in Cypress you need to interact with it via a task.

Here's a basic connection task taken from the Snowflake docs.

**cypress.config.js**

```js
const { defineConfig } = require("cypress");
var snowflake = require("snowflake-sdk");

let connectionId;

module.exports = defineConfig({
  e2e: {
    setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
      on("task", {
        snowflake: () => {
          var connection = snowflake.createConnection({
            account: "account",
            username: "user",
            password: "password",
            application: "application",
          });

          connection.connect(function (err, conn) {
            if (err) {
              console.error("Unable to connect: " + err.message);
            } else {
              console.log("Successfully connected to Snowflake.");
              // Optional: store the connection ID.
              connectionId = conn.getId();
            }
          })
          return null
        },
      });
    },
  },
})
```

**Test**

```js
it('Connect to snowflake', () => {
  cy.task('snowflake')
})
```

Without proper credentials, it produces a connection error but proves the package is working.

> Unable to connect: Request to Snowflake failed.